# How to use remaining annual leave when manager will not respond?

Tags: resignation, leave

I have given notice to leave the company and have asked to take my few days remaining annual leave during this period, my email requests have been ignored, manager never available for telephone conversation.

How can I determine if I can take my remaining annual leave during this time?

Comment: Hi Debbie, I edited your question to make it more on topic here.  If I change the intent too much feel free to [edit] to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Do note that, if "annual leave" is similar to "PTO" or "vacation time", in many cases, taking time off when you've already given notice is considered bad form. Your notice period is intended for you to sit down with someone and explain the status of all of your projects and tasks, or to teach someone how you do task X (if you're the go-to person for task X), and you can't do that if you're not there.

Comment: @AdamV That depends on country and contract. Where I live, notice periods are typically longer than your full annual leave, so not taking the rest of your paid leave in that time would be foolish. Therefor, leaving before your notice period is up is perfectly normal here (you may not start the other job in the time you got paid time off with your former job though).

Comment: @AdamV no Leave/PTO is part of your contractual rights of course you take it

Answer (score 9):

I would send an email to your manager, his boss and HR stating your intentions. It's important that his boss and HR get it as well because he's obviously dropping the ball and you need to make sure that there is as much record as possible in case they try to dock you the hours you're taking as leave by saying "you didn't request leave".

Make sure that you put **all** relevant details, including the fact that you've made multiple attempts to go through your manager but haven't been successful and that you're only doing it this way because time is growing short.

Comment: To this I would add, have you checked your contract and HR policy manual. I have never worked in a copmany where taking vaaction was permitted after giving notice.

Comment: I have been paid for remaining vacation as well as been allowed to take the remaining vacation as the last week of employment. I'm sure it varies by company and I'm almost certain that laws will vary by state. That's been my personal experience anyway.

Comment: THat's why it is important to check before continuing to ask.

Comment: I would phone HR rather than burning more time emailing them and hoping for a reply.

Comment: @Carson63000: While phoning probably can't hurt, the (virtual) paper trail is still important. At least the final agreement should be in writing.

Comment: @HLGEM: That depends on local/company culture and rules. In Germany, employers are _required by law_ to let the employee take remaining vacation during the notice period, unless that is impractical, in which case it is paid out.